# 最初の文字のみ大文字に変更したい

Tags: java

Javaを使って文字列を以下のように条件で加工したいです
①大文字
②小文字
③最初の文字だけ大文字でそれ以降は小文字

条件式と大文字小文字は自己解決できたのですが、
③の加工の適切な方法がわかりません。

以上、お手数をおかけしますがご確認お願いいたします。
わかりにくい面があればご指摘お願いいたします。

Comment: 参考: [Makes the first letter caps and the rest lowercase](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Makesthefirstlettercapsandtherestlowercase.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

英語版Stack Overflowでの類似質問に対して回答がいくつか付いていますが、

[How to capitalize the first letter of a String in Java? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3904579/2322778)

そのうちの一つに [@Elenasys さんの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768694/2322778) で、「コードが短くて速いバージョン」が紹介されています。

```
String name  = "stackoverflow"; 
name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: cubick さん
うまく探せてませんでした。ありがとうございます。